# ler uma serie de elementos json (gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

Seguinte, estou tentando escrever um metodo em java que leia uma serie de objetos json utilizando o gson do gogle. So que não esta funcionando. Não sei se e o meu codigo ou o meu arquivo, seguem os dois ai em baixo:

- classe cliente:

```java
public class Cliente {
    String id;
    String nome;
    String email;

    public Cliente() {
    }
}
```

- metodo que le o json e retorna o cliente:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LerComGSON {


   public static Cliente json2java(){
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       try{
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("clientes.json"));
           Cliente cliente = gson.fromJson(br, Cliente.class);
           return cliente;

       } catch (IOException  e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }

}
```

- json:

```
{   
    "CLIENTE1":{"ID":24828,"NOME":"Verona Boyer","EMAIL":"Charity_Hane34@gmail.com"},
    "CLIENTE2":{"ID":33144,"NOME":"Rosetta Wuckert","EMAIL":"Carson.Bernhard@hotmail.com"},
    "CLIENTE3":{"ID":67592,"NOME":"Tianna Runte II","EMAIL":"London89@hotmail.com"},
    "CLIENTE4":{"ID":38309,"NOME":"Howard Champlin","EMAIL":"Myrna.Buckr@hotmail.com"}
}
```

> o codigo acima deveira ler o primeiro objeto "CLIENTE1" e retornar um objeto cliente com ID, NOME e EMAIL, porem retorna um objeto cliente com todos os campos vazios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa acertar o seu clientes.json:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 24828,
    "nome": "Verona Boyer",
    "email": "Charity_Hane34@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 33144,
    "nome": "Rosetta Wuckert",
    "email": "Carson.Bernhard@hotmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 67592,
    "nome": "Tianna Runte II",
    "email": "London89@hotmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 38309,
    "nome": "Howard Champlin",
    "email": "Myrna.Buckr@hotmail.com"
  }
]
```

Seu json representa vários clientes. Precisa acertar também:

```java
Cliente[] clientes = gson.fromJson(br, Cliente[].class);
```

E consequentemente o retorno do seu método:

```java
public static Cliente[] json2java(){
  //ignorando o restante dos códigos.
}
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui cara, muito obrigado <3